# CRUD operations in PHP using Json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to preform create,read,update and delete operations.. Struck with writing functions...

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" size="50" placeholder="Add New">
<button type="submit">Add New</button>
</form>
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
     //Display here<button type="submit">Delete</button> 
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am having a json file  to store the textbox value,and a php file for performing operations..

```
        <?php
        class CrudService
        {
          function_construct(argument)
          {

          }
            function create(){
            if (isset($_POST['mytext'])) {
            $try_array = $_POST['mytext'];
            $file_content = file_get_contents('data.json');
            $json_file = json_decode($file_content,true);
            array_push($json_file->result, $try_array);
            $json_file = json_decode($file_content);
            }
           }

           function read(){
             $file_content = file_get_contents('data.json');
             return $file_content;
           }

           function update(){
            file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($json_file));
            $jfo = json_decode($json_file);
            $posts = $jfo->result->posts;
            foreach($posts as $key => $post){
            return $post;
            }

           }    

           function delete(){
            $file = file_get_contents('data.json');
            $data = json_decode($file);
            file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($json_file));
            $json_decode = json_decode($json_encode, true);
            foreach ($json_decode as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array('title', $value)) {
                unset($json_decode[$key]);
            }
            }
            $json_encode = json_encode($json_decode);
            return $json_encode;
           }
        }   
        ?>
```

The entered value of the textbox should be stored in json array as a key value pair,and retrieved back upon submit and delete action should be done upon clicking delete..

Comment: whats the result ? any errors?

Comment: add name attribute in you form's input field.

Comment: also completly change class code